# Paginacion SQL para un chat

Tags: sql-server

Hola a todos estaba realizando un chat ,todo normal pero me di cuenta que tendria que paginarlo, ya que si cargaba 50 para más , tomaba mas tiempo en cargar, dicho eso quise paginarlo pero me di cuenta que paginarlo de manera normal no era mi solucion.

Explico :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora no puedo dar un order by por la fecha de envió ,  que me daría lo siguiente.
Tendría que ser tal como me da un select normal,de principio a fin 
Ya que al recorro la tabla con un **FOR** y lo pongo por la cantidad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si quisiera paginar, tendria que ser algo asi 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede hacer algo asi, o es imposible?
En realidad ese problema lo solucioné con programación, cuenta cuantos hay, y lo recorro al revés.
Pero al ver este tipo de problemas me gustaría aprender.
Si alguien tiene que tendría que buscar específicamente me ayudaría, estoy indagando pero no encuentro de tal manera.
Gracias

Comment: puedes usar `limit` para limitar los resultados `select * from mensaje where usuario = 2 LIMIT 10 order by id desc` obtenemos los 10 ultimos chat  si el usuario quiere mas resultados `select * from mensaje where usuario = 2 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10  order by id desc` obtenemos los ultimos 20 pero omitiendo los primeros 10 osea del 11 en adelante y si quiere mas solo le damos a offset 10 mas osea 20 y asi sucecivamente ! no requieres paginacion solo investigar alguito mas!

Answer (score 1):

Para paginar en SQL Server existen las opciones OFFSET FETCH desde la versión 2012.

```
SELECT *
FROM Mensajes
ORDER BY ID
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY;
```

Recuerda que SQL Server primero va a obtener todas las líneas y después filtrará las que le pidas con esta opción.

Answer (score 0):

en la primera consulta debes obtener un **top 10** ordenado de forma ascendente por el campo **ID** y ese campo guardarlo(**@ID_ultima_consulta**) para realizar las paginaciones, al momento de buscar los siguientes 10 registros(la siguiente pagina de datos), debes obtener top 10 pero con un **where ID>@ID_ultima_consulta**.
Este sería el script:

Primera consulta.

```
SELECT top 10 * FROM Mesajes Order By ID;
```

Segunda consulta.

```
SELECT top 10 * FROM Mesajes Where ID>@ID_ultima_consulta Order By ID;
```

Comment: Esta bien pero me daria el mismo resultado de la segunda foto.

Answer (score -1):

Para poder pagina debes de utilizar LIMIT y OFFSET en tu QUERY.

LIMIT te servirá para indicar el numero de items que quieres devolver, (en tu caso 50)
y OFFSET a partir de que item quieres que te devuelve.

Ejemplo

```
SELECT * FROM Mesajes LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0;
SELECT * FROM Mesajes LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50;
SELECT * FROM Mesajes LIMIT 50 OFFSET 100;
```

etc..

Comment: En SQL Server no existe `LIMIT`, supongo que te refieres al `TOP`